# How to change android account of a phone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-account, huawei

I want to use different Google Account for my Android phone (Huawei Mate8). When I did Factory Reset, Android did not allow me to use another account, it says (Please sign in using the owner's account of this phone). In this case, I cannot sell the phone since the new owner will not be able to add its account. How do I eliminate this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to settings and then accounts choose add account and then add the other e mail id that you want to, after that go to Google under accounts where both your accounts will be displayed, there delete the previous one and it'll be gone

Comment: Thank you very much. As I said in the question, I did Factory reset. Also I cannot login the owner's Google account, *I made a huge mistake by using 2-step verification via Google Auth App that I installed before resetting* :(, is there an alternative way instead of that?

Comment: Trying skipping sign in if it is possible assuming its possible since new phones allow that and then try, [ https://support.google.com/android-one/answer/6088915?hl=en-GB accord ding to this thread https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/gmail/KyLff1ZQ4-M many have the same problem but only that worked. So try full deletion as mentioned in the former link